# Is there a Command in Visual Studio for "Navigate to this item in TFS Source Explorer"

Tags: visual-studio

I want add a command to the R-Click context menu in the Solution Explorer that would navigate the TFS Source Explorer window to the right location corresponding to the item in question.

However I can't see how to do it simply without writing a VS extension, which I want to avoid at all costs.

It's not that I don't want  extensions. I just don't want to write a custom one. Previously I'd be able to use macros but those were removed in these versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: You've mentioned not wanting extensions... I get that, but I feel I have to mention Shift-Alt-L for ReSharper. It navigates to the file in question in Solution Explorer (not TFS). A few other greats are Control-Shift-T for navigate to filename, Control T for navigate to class. I'm sorry these aren't supported by native VS =(

Comment: @Sprague - Thanks, I'm very familiar with resharper - I have used it for years, but it's absolutely not what I need and from what you're saying it's of no help whatsoever anyway. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, well, I love not being of service. I don't think such a key combination exists. Good luck. Somebody else may find those short cuts useful, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

The [VSCommands](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features-SolutionExplorer#solutionexplorer-enhancements-locateinsolution) extension will give you the option to locate a file in TFS and in the Solution Explorer

[image]

Comment: Woweeee! Will look a this.

Comment: Later: I've looked at the support site and there are **so many questions that are just not answered** I'm very reticent to buy a license (as the free version doesn't have this functionality) until I know what support is available for this - paging @jarekkardas. Thanks and I hope that there are other options too.

Comment: I can't answer to that, as I've never needed to use the support. All I can say is that it's been fairly stable for me. That said, I've never paid for a license, and I have this functionality, I don't actually think it properly disables functionality after the trial ends. Either that, or I get the beta which comes out on new VS releases and it doesn't properly disable there. I'd recommend trying the trial and see if it disables once the trial expires.

Answer (score 1):

The [Locate in TFS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexPendleton.LocateinTFS2017) adds a context menu entry *Locate in TFS* to Solution Explorer and Open Tabs.

[image: Locate in TFS Context Menus in Solution Explorer and Tabs]